# shipping address is missing out on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, knockout

I don't know why but i get an error js on checkout. 
When I'm on the payment step, The shipping address Below the choice of method of payment is absent.
The problem come from an error with Knockout.
Nevertheless i refresh cache, deploy static files, delete folder pub/static but I still have the problem

I inspected with firebug and find this error there :

```
TypeError : $parent.getCode is not a function
```

I searched the forum but found nothing

Here is the capture of the step of payment and firebug :

[image]

[image]

Would anyone have an idea?
Thanks for your help

Comment: The shipping address works with a different theme loaded?

Comment: yes with the theme Luma, the adress is loaded!!It's very strange

Comment: Have you tried enabling a free shipping method?

Comment: yes, i create a custom module for free shipping!

Comment: but did you try it WITHOUT your custom module? (Using a built in shipping method that you confirmed is working)

Comment: yes, i tried without my custom module and i get the error too, unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58057/discussion-between-strauss-and-brentwpeterson).